# PS1 prompt based on who logged in

Tags: bash, users, prompt

I've got a nice PS1 prompt that I want to only be used when user 'gatty' uses su for root.

`PS1='\[\e[32m\]#\[\e[37m\] '`

When other users like 'george' etc login, I want them to get the standard PS1 instead of 'gattys'.

Is this possible, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In root's `.bashrc`, check the contents of `/proc/self/loginuid`, and set your custom `PS1` variable only if it equals your UID.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you :D